# How to fix this ruby gem installation error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

on a Windows 7 environment, 
i installed ruby 2.2 and and the ruby development kit and want to install a gem now, which throws this error:

error: unknown type name 'BOOL'

for the command

gem install av_capture -v '1.0.1'

on multiple .h files. The av_capture gem is part of a 'bundle install' i want to do for another gem.

I also get one
fatal error: AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h: No such file or directory

So i doubt that av_capture gem can be installed at all (?)

Google tells me to use g++ instead of gcc to fix the bool type error, i dont think that i can adjust this for the ruby devkit though.

The DevKit itself seems to work fine, the example json part of the devkit wiki installation site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked up this gem, as it says everywhere on their site:

**Wraps up AVCapture and exposes it to Ruby. This gem only works on OS X.**

So I doubt you're going to get this to work. AVFoundation is an IOS Specific thing.

Comment: Thanks, that would explain my issues. Wish the publisher of the gem i actually wanted to use mentioned it is for OS X somewhere :-)